# How to get folder names using powershell or any windows script?

Tags: powershell, filesystems

Say I have following file structure

```
L:\Enterprise\Legal\Planning\Contacts\A-D\
```

Under A-D I have 50 Folders which is named after company name. So it looks like this

```
L:\Enterprise\Legal\Planning\Contacts\A-D\3-M Company\subfolder\sub-subfolder\files.txt
L:\Enterprise\Legal\Planning\Contacts\A-D\ABC Company\subfolder\sub-subfolder\files.txt
L:\Enterprise\Legal\Planning\Contacts\A-D\XYZ Company\subfolder\sub-subfolder\files.txt
L:\Enterprise\Legal\Planning\Contacts\A-D\AAA Company\subfolder\sub-subfolder\files.txt
```

Is there a way to get the company name from the above file structure using powershell or some windows script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your goal is to have a list of company name one way is:

```
cd L:\Enterprise\Legal\Planning\Contacts\A-D\

dir | select -expand fullname | % { ($_ -split '\\')[6] }
```

Some people may also find that this works instead

```
dir | select -expand fullname | % { ($_ -split '\\')[7] }
```

Comment: C.B is this powershell or dos?

Comment: @ShawnTorres Absolutely Powershell.

Comment: I go into the folder. type in the command. another powershell prompt comes. No out of of the directory names. any idea

Comment: I am getting this error after adding the export. Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:1 char:71
+ dir | select -expand fullname | % { ($_ -split '\\')[6] } | Export-Csv <<<<  c:\temp\inactive-a.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCo
   mmand

Comment: dir | select -expand fullname | % { ($_ -split '\\')[6] } gave me A-D 160 times. It did not give me the company names.

Comment: @ShawnTorres It dependes on how many parts you have after the split start counting from 0. In your example I cont till 6. You accepted my answer, I think you solve it rigth?

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing a list of files/folders from a CSV, you could do this:

```
$strings = Import-CSV -Path "C:\PathToCSV.csv"
foreach ($string in $strings) {
    $string -replace 'L:\\Enterprise\\Legal\\Planning\\Contacts\\A-D\\' -replace '\\subfolder\\sub-subfolder\\files.txt'
}
```

Note the double-slashes (\\). You have to escape the slashes, otherwise they are treated as special. Output should look like:

```
3-M Company
ABC Company
XYZ Company
AAA Company
```